# Understanding SEC Filings

Tags: documents

I apologize for this question sounding vague.

I want to be able to read SEC filings and from those, get a good sense of a public company's financials. However, when I go to sec.gov 's website, all I see is a bunch of different types of filings and do not know where to start.

Question: What are the most important SEC filings to read to understand a company's financials -- and what is a good tutorial for explaining them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most important filings are:

Form **10-K**, which is the annual report required by the U.S. Securities and Exchange Commission (SEC)

and

Form **10-Q**, for the interim quarters.

Comment: Could you possibly expand the answer to explain generally what the fillings are and contain?

Answer (score 2):

There are a whole host of types of filings. Some of them are only relevant to companies that are publicly traded, and other types are general to just registered corps in general.

### There are a few really popular ones:

- Form D: investments
- Form 10-K: annual report, often includes earnings
- Form 10-Q: quarterly report, often includes earnings info
- Form S-1: initial registration for IPO
- Form S-4: mergers & acquisitions
- Form S-8: employee stock incentives

... and many more: http://reportstream.io/explore/has-form

### How much you can read them depends on the formats:

- Some forms are actually just scanned PDFs, and you have to go read the scans.
- some other form submissions are in a parsed text format
- some others like 10-K's have big fancy HTML versions that are very human readible
- some are an XML-like format

### Some companies don't submit their forms on time or at all

- As you may have seen with the recent SUNE (now SUNEQ) earnings debacle... some companies withhold their earnings, and thus the reliability of the information can be wishy-washy if the company isn'y following the SEC filings rules properly.
- In my experience, Private companies tend to not disclose a lot of financial information, so you have to get creative sometimes to deduce things about the financial health of the company.

**Overall, reading SEC filings is hard, and for some, the explanations of those filings is worth paying for.**

**Source:** I  am currently trying to build a product that solves this problem.